# calling cgi/py within PHP with parameters

Tags: php, python, variables, cgi

I am trying to execute a cgi/python script from within php, and at the same time pass the cgi/python script a paramter.

in my php I have

```
<? echo exec('/var/www/cgi-bin/test.cgi ' + $_POST["var"]); ?>
```

However it doesn't work, and in the apache log it says 'sh:0 not Found'

This test script is very simple :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cgi, sys, os

for arg in sys.argv:
    print arg
```

Comment: In PHP, the string concatenation operator is `.`, not `+`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As someone pointed out, the string concatenation operator in PHP is `.`, not `+`.

The result of "adding" non-numeric strings is 0. That's why the shell tries to run the command "0" and returns error: "sh:0 not found".

Try this:

```
exec('/var/www/cgi-bin/test.cgi ' . escapeshellcmd($_POST["var"]));
```

Also, note that shell command arguments should be escaped with [escapeshellcmd](http://www.php.net/manual/function.escapeshellcmd.php).